# Renaming Loop for files in Linux

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to create a for loop that goes through a directory, and renames each file in that directory.

```
dir2=$1

for i in $dir2
do
file=$(basename "$i")
b=${file%.*}
c=${file#"$stub"}
d=-BACKUP
e=$b$d$c
mv "$i" "$e"
```

I'm trying to change each file:i to become $e.

For example, if I have a directory, and there is one file in it called test.txt, the file would be changed to test-BACKUP.txt

I'm having problems in that it's not changing the files withing the directories, it's changing the directory itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in "$dir2/"*; do
    mv "$i" "${i%.*}-BACKUP.${i##*.}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped significantly. Could you please explain the significance of the syntax for `"${i%.*}-BACKUP${i##*.}"` I'm very new to Bash and sometimes the syntax can be very annoying to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *
do
  echo $i
  mv $i `basename $i`.new
done
```